# Case Function in Oracle - wrong return

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have an table with these fields:

`id,
quarter,
description,
id_school.`

These table have this data:

```
ID | quarter | description 

12   A         1 YEAR         
12   S         1 Year         
12   A          DONE
```

I want to get the `serie_school` based on the below query:

```
select NVL(
    case 
        WHEN quarter  = 'S' AND 
             (UPPER(description ) LIKE 'DONE' OR 
              UPPER(description ) LIKE '%YEAR' OR  
              UPPER(description ) LIKE 'LANGUAGE') THEN -1 
        WHEN quarter  = 'A' AND 
            (UPPER(description ) LIKE 'DONE' OR  
             UPPER(description ) LIKE '%QUARTER' OR  
             UPPER(description ) LIKE '%STEP' OR 
             UPPER(description ) LIKE 'LANGUAGE') THEN -1 
        WHEN quarter  = 'T' THEN -1 
        ELSE -1 
    end, -1) nvl_return from test
```

The return of this on my query is:

```
ID | quarter | description | nvl_return 

12   A         1 YEAR         1
12   S         1 Year         1 *- (this column has the wrong answer)*
12   A          DONE         -1
```

The answer of line 2 is wrong, because the `QUARTER` field is `'S'` and the description field have `'year'`, so it needs to be `-1`, but in Oracle is returning `1`.

Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: To the original poster:  Please edit the query (and keep the formatting!).  In the subsequent edits, all the `THEN`s were turned to `-1`, so the question no longer makes sense.  (The first editor probably owes you an apology.)

Comment: It appears that even in the original unformatted question that every path through the `case` statement returned -1.  It appears that the original question was posted incorrectly.

Comment: @shawnt00 He's got `UPPER` there

Comment: @t.s. Yeah, I literally just noticed. But isn't the `NVL()`pointless?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the answers. It is my first time at Stackoverflow, so I think I made a mistake when tried to make a question. I simulated the names of tables and fields, but the content not. I have a big query here, but the content and the structure is the same. The wrong thing is, the field that have 'S' and '1 Year' is not been recognized as it. And then it shows 1. I have verified if there is space or something else, but not.

Comment: Still, you probably have something, like invisible character  after `'1 Year'`. Here `'1 Year<you don't see me>'`. Or here `'%YEAR'`. Re-type the data and see

Comment: @shawnt00 yes, but this is different question

Comment: I tell you even more. One time an invisible character got into my oracle script and I couldn't execute `execute immediate 'statement';`. But when I did  `execute immediate variable;` it worked fine. So, try to paste your code into notepad and then open new script file and copy from notepad into that new script file. I was using sql developer

Comment: @AlexandreMagalhesDonnertSom - Every path through your `case` statement still returns -1.  Given the code you posted, it is impossible for any row to have a `nvl_return` value of anything other than -1.  Yet 2 of your three sample rows have a value of 1.  That implies that the code you posted is incorrect.  Once you correct the code, I would guess that @TS's supposition is correct and your actual data has characters after the word "year".  I'd guess a trailing space, carriage return, or line feed.

Comment: @t.s. I suspect that we're not getting the full story in the question and the `NVL()` thing is just one more sign of that.

Answer (score 1):

Alexandre,

Examine your statement, where I have added "<======" to point out the various possible amounts for this column.

```
select NVL(
    case 
        WHEN quarter  = 'S' AND 
             (UPPER(description ) LIKE 'DONE' OR 
              UPPER(description ) LIKE '%YEAR' OR  
              UPPER(description ) LIKE 'LANGUAGE') THEN -1<======= 
        WHEN quarter  = 'A' AND 
            (UPPER(description ) LIKE 'DONE' OR  
             UPPER(description ) LIKE '%QUARTER' OR  
             UPPER(description ) LIKE '%STEP' OR 
             UPPER(description ) LIKE 'LANGUAGE') THEN -1<====== 
        WHEN quarter  = 'T' THEN -1 <======
        ELSE -1 <=======
    end, -1 <-this will never happen) nvl_return from test
```

You return "-1" in every single case.  "-1" is the only value returned, by the only column returned in your query.

So when you say the results are:

```
ID | quarter | description | nvl_return 

12   A         1 YEAR         1
12   S         1 Year         1 *- (this column has the wrong answer)*
12   A          DONE         -1
```

Unfortunately, your query cannot produce the results you've stated.

Try creating a SQL fiddle, to explain the issue. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0c449/1)

Comment: Hi guys, the problem was that the field QUARTER were coming with an invisible character after the letter. I could not reproduce all the SQL query due to it has a lot of joins. I put an TRIM function to the field quarter and it solved the problem. Thanks a lot!